# Groovy - Ambiguous method overloading for method

Tags: parsing, groovy, wsdl

I have checked forums already, find some tips about this problem but none of exactly match mine.

I got this exception just after calling WSDLParse.parse method.
By the way , I am trying to update my Groovy version 2.2.1 to 2.4.3, do I miss something?

Thanks for your advice

Ps: This is the exception message, below you can find all stacktrace.

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.predic8.schema.Element#setType.
    Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
            [class javax.xml.namespace.QName]
            [class groovy.xml.QName]

```
  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.predic8.schema.Element#setType.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class javax.xml.namespace.QName]
        [class groovy.xml.QName]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:3238)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3191)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3134)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getNormalMethodWithCaching(MetaClassImpl.java:1369)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCaching(MetaClassImpl.java:1284)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1054)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MultipleSetterProperty.setProperty(MultipleSetterProperty.java:52)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2663)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3746)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.setProperty(XMLElement.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:530)
        at com.predic8.schema.Element.parseAttributes(Element.groovy:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.ja
va:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:40)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.predic8.schema.Schema.parseChildren(Schema.groovy:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.ja
va:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:45)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.Types.parseChildren(Types.groovy:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.ja
va:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:45)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions.parseChildren(Definitions.groovy:220)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.ja
va:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:45)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.parseLocal(WSDLParser.groovy:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.ja
va:207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at com.predic8.soamodel.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.groovy:34)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.super$2$parse(WSDLParser.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.parse(WSDLParser.groovy:24)
        at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser$parse.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
        at ESBWsdlRequest.<init>(ESBWsdlRequest.groovy:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java
:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:268)
        at YOKSIS_OGRENCI_SIL_in.run(YOKSIS_OGRENCI_SIL_in.groovy:2)
        at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:589)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.xslt.ESBGroovyEngine.execute(ESBGroovyEngine.java:21)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.xslt.Transformer.transformGroovy(Transformer.java:102)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.xslt.Transformer.transformIn(Transformer.java:63)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.xslt.XsltProcessor.processBag(XsltProcessor.java:92)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.common.GenericProcessor.processTypeBag(GenericProcessor.java:27)
        at com.fibabanka.esi.common.GenericProcessor.process(GenericProcessor.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:340)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:237)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:322)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:213)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:248)
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:160)
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I didn't set element nor set propety. Also I didn't use any QName class in my script.
This is my groovy script file->

```
import groovy.time.BaseDuration.From;
import groovy.util.XmlParser;
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper;
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions;
import com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser;
import com.predic8.wstool.creator.RequestTemplateCreator;
import com.predic8.wstool.creator.SOARequestCreator;

class ESBWsdlParser {
    String formTemplate;
    String requestSoapXml;
    public ESBWsdlRequest(String wsdlFile,String operationName) {
        File file = new File(wsdlFile);
        println file.getAbsolutePath();

        WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();
        Definitions wsdl = parser.parse(wsdlFile);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        SOARequestCreator creator = new SOARequestCreator(wsdl, new RequestTemplateCreator(), new MarkupBuilder(writer));
        //creator.createRequest(PortType name, Operation name, Binding name);
        creator.createRequest(null, operationName, null);
        formTemplate = writer.toString();

    }
    public String resolveName(c){
        String[] arParts = c.name().toString().split("}");
        if(arParts.length > 1){
            return  arParts[1];
        }
        return c.name;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there are two object-compatible and single-argument setType methods and you call it with `null`. Or to be more precise, you don't call the method, you set the property, which results in the method call.

Now before Groovy 2.4 we had no support for the overloaded case. Which method was invoked was actually random. In other words, you had luck if it always called the right method for your cases. Since Groovy 2.4, Groovy supports overloaded setter, but this can then lead to cases, in which the setter overload causes exceptions like the one above. Something I consider good, since it shows something that could have caused mysterious errors in the past.

The fix is not as nice... `setType((QName) qname))` instead of the property assignment.... of course with the QName class of your choice. You can use of course Keegan's suggestion to support you in that

EDIT: changed setElement to setType

Comment: Well, I didn't set property nor set element in my code. That's weird (I will update my question right now, please have a look at it)

Comment: I think @blackdrag meant `Element.setType()`, and not `setElement()`.  But he's right about the cause.  You may not be calling this method, but Membrane _is_, as part of the stuff `parse()` does.

Comment: Thank you very much blackdrag as always a response from you is normally gold. 

We found out where our conflict was happening by running the script below. We found out quickly our conflict was between a user lib at user/.groovy/lib/jaxrpc.jar  and our jdk at  jre/lib/rt.jar . Removing the jaxrpc.jar was the correct option in our scenario. 

```import javax.xml.namespace.QName
Class klass = QName.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");

println location
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably [ask](https://github.com/membrane/soa-model/issues) SOA Membrane to edit [Element](https://github.com/membrane/soa-model/blob/master/core/src/main/groovy/com/predic8/schema/Element.groovy)'s

```
type = getTypeQName(token.getAttributeValue( null , 'type'))
```

to something like

```
type = (QName) getTypeQName(token.getAttributeValue( null , 'type'))
```

to resolve the ambiguity.  In the mean time, you can manually override yourself, like this

```java
@Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.1.3')
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.5')

// for some reason, this isn't able to resolve in my GroovyConsole -- I had to download into my .groovy/lib
//@GrabResolver(name='membrane', root='http://repository.membrane-soa.org/content/repositories/releases')
//@Grab(group='com.predic8', module='soa-model-core', version='1.5.3')

// for some reason, I'm getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.predic8.schema.SchemaComponent due to missing dependency Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" in my GroovyConsole when I don't have this
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true, initContextClassLoader=true)

import com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions
import com.predic8.wsdl.Operation
import com.predic8.wsdl.PortType
import com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser

import com.predic8.schema.Declaration
import javax.xml.namespace.QName as JQName
import groovy.xml.QName

// the fix
MetaMethod originalSetType = Declaration.metaClass.getMetaMethod("setType", [Object])
Declaration.metaClass.setType = { Object obj ->
   if (obj)
       originalSetType.invoke((QName) obj)
}

// an example usage, demonstrating fix works
Definitions defs = new WSDLParser().parse("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL")
for (PortType pt : defs.portTypes) {
    println pt.name
    for (Operation op : pt.operations)
      println "  -${op.name}"
}
```

Since you're using classes (I assume in a compiled project), you could probably put the fix in a static block.

Comment: I guess, I need to upgrade my soa-model-core to 1.5.3 as well

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 1.6.0. E.g. for Gradle build script:

```
compile "com.predic8:soa-model-core:1.6.0"
```